# Downloading an image from facebook in android

Tags: java, android, facebook

this one has been probably been asked around a million times already (and indeed i've read so many solutions, none of which worked).

Im trying to download an image from the currently logged user into an android app, i've already got the token and a picture link in previous steps from the "link" field.

now im stuck with downloading the actual bitmap into the app so i may display it inside an image view (im using sdk 4.2 btw).

here's what i've got :

```
imageUrl = new URL("https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=123064554517565&set=a.123064551184232.25323.100004420628675&type=1");
InputStream stream = (InputStream) imageUrl.getContent();
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
```

this is what im getting back from the logCat:

```
06-17 22:39:07.326: I/System.out(9239): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
06-17 22:39:07.326: I/System.out(9239): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
06-17 22:39:07.326: I/System.out(9239): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
06-17 22:39:07.326: I/System.out(9239): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
06-17 22:39:07.761: V/BitmapFactory(9239): DecodeImagePath(decodeResourceStream3) : res/drawable-xxhdpi/checkbox_on.png
06-17 22:39:07.761: I/System.out(9239): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
06-17 22:39:08.241: I/System.out(9239): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
06-17 22:39:08.786: D/skia(9239): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) library and all your problems will be gone. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [AQuery](https://github.com/androidquery/androidquery/releases/tag/0.26.8) Library or Picasso

Here's an example to how to use AQuery

First add this.

```
private AQuery aq;
```

and this in your onCreated

```
aq = new AQuery(MainActivity.this);
```

and finally, here's the code to download a image, `R.drawable.defaultImageError`is just a default image if the download fail in some point.

```
urlImg = "https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=123064554517565&set=a.123064551184232.25323.100004420628675&type=1";
aq.id(R.id.facebookImage).progress(R.id.progress).image(urlImg, true, true, 0, R.drawable.defaultImageError);
```